# Неправильно работает сложение векторов, выдает неверный ответ и срабатывает точка останова (delete_scalar)

Tags: c++

Неправильно работает сложение векторов, выдает неверный ответ и срабатывает точка останова (delete_scalar).

**Vector.h:**

```
class Vector
{
    double* a;
    int size;
    int count;

public:
    Vector();      
    Vector(int s); 
    ~Vector();       
    double& operator[](int index); 
    friend Vector operator+(Vector v1, Vector v2);
    void setarray(); 
    void getarray();    
};
```

**Vector.cpp:**

```
Vector::Vector()
{
    size = 10;
    a = new double[size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i != size; i++) {
        a[i] = 0.0;
    }
}

Vector::Vector(int s)
{
    if (s > 0) {
        size = s;
        a = new double[size];
        for (size_t i = 0; i != size; i++) {
            a[i] = 0.0;
        }
    }
    else cout << "Size can't be negativ";
}

Vector::~Vector()
{
    delete[]a;
}

double& Vector::operator[](int index)
{
    if (index <= size) {
        return a[index];
    }
    else {
        cout << "Элемента по данному индексу нет" << endl;
    }
}


void Vector::setarray()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i != size; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}

void Vector::getarray()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i != size; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
}

Vector operator+(Vector v1, Vector v2)
{
    Vector v3(v1.size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != v1.size; i++) {
        v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
    }
    return v3;
}
```

**Main.cpp:**

```
int main()
{
    Vector a(2);
    Vector b(2);
    a.setarray();
    b.setarray();
    (a + b).getarray();
   
}
```

Вызвыно исключение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Почему то размер v1 = 16447572, а не 6. это как?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очень опасный код. как будет работать сложение двух векторов разного размера?

Comment: Вместо вывода cout в operator[] нужно либо бросать исключение, либо придумывать, что возвращать

Comment: Какой именно ответ выдаёт и где стоит точка останова?

Comment: @Илья К думаю для векторов одинакового размера

Comment: В своём коде (приложен в чате под моим ответом) Вы не полностью воспроизвели код конструктора копирования, который я написал. Посмотрите внимательнее. То, что идёт после скобок и двоеточия (`size(other.size), count(other.count)`), очень важно, потому что именно там производится переприсваивание атрибутов `size`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я потратил некоторое время и нашёл решение Вашей проблемы. В методе `operator+` вызывается `return v3;`, что, по сути, вызывает **копирование** только что созданного вектора из метода `operator+` в вызывающую функцию. Т.к. вызывается именно копирование, срабатывает стандартный конструктор копирования, т.е. все поля класса просто-напросто дублируются в новом объекте, **в том числе и указатель `a`**. А т.к. после выхода из метода (а, следовательно, и из области видимости) объект `v3` разрушается, то, как Вы указали в деструкторе, память, выделенная под массив `a`, освобождается. Итого получаем, что после возврата значения из метода `operator+` в вызывающей функции у Вас остаётся объект `Vector`, у которого атрибут `a` является невалидным указателем на очищенную память. Отсюда и ошибки.

Чтобы избежать данной проблемы, Вам следует определить конструктор копирования, который бы корректно осуществлял перенос значений динамической памяти в новый объект. Я сделал это так:

```cpp
Vector::Vector(const Vector& other): size(other.size), count(other.count)
{
    a = new double[other.size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < other.size; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = other.a[i];
    }
}
```

Здесь я в новом объекте выделяю для `a` новую память и копирую в неё значения из копируемого объекта. Таким образом, в вызывающей функции останется объект `Vector`, у которого поле `a` будет указывать на действительные данные.

Comment: вставил ваш код в программу, сейчас вызывается окошко "вызвано исключение" в строчке v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i]; , что делать?

Comment: @ggame больше ничего не меняли в программе? Сейчас я просмотрю всё ещё раз на предмет изменений у себя, может что-то забыл в ответе показать

Comment: не изменял, просто вставил пока что

Comment: @ggame А в хедере объявление конструктора дописали?

Comment: проверил. да, дописал объявление конструктора в хедере

Comment: Я сейчас снова полностью скопировал Ваш код, вставил себе, добавил только конструктор копирования и всё, у меня всё работает. Вы объявление в public-секцию добавили? (простите за глупый вопрос, но я считаю, что тут уже проблема кроется в какой-то опечатке)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116128/discussion-between-v-mor-and-ggame).